# map in K-theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-k-theory

I have a very stupid question on a map I have seen in K-theory.

The situation is as follows: $X$ is a smooth variety over a field $k$ and $\iota: Z \to X$ is the inclusion of a smooth closed subvariety. Then one looks at the Zariski sheaf $\mathcal{K}_{n, X}$ (resp. $\mathcal{K}_{n, Z}$) on $X$ (resp. on $Z$) associated to Quillen's K-theory. People use the map

$$
\mathcal{K}_{n, X} \longrightarrow \iota_\ast \mathcal{K}_{n, Z}
$$

What is this map? Is it just the composition of $\iota^\ast: \mathcal{K}_{n, X} \to \mathcal{K}_{n, Z}$ and $\iota_\ast: \mathcal{K}_{n, Z} \to \mathcal{K}_{n, X}$ given by functoriality? Is it true that the latter one is injective?

Comment: $\iota_\ast\mathcal{K}_{n,Z}$ is the pushforward sheaf on $X$ which assigns to the open $V\subseteq X$ the group $K_n(V\times_ZX)$. The map $\mathcal{K}_{n,X}\to\iota_\ast\mathcal{K}_{n,Z}$ is then given by the pullback map $\iota_V^\ast:K_n(V)\to K_n(V\times_ZX)$. You probably don't want to consider the $\iota^\ast$ and $\iota_\ast$ as maps between sheaves on different spaces - the way you wrote it in the question does not seem to make sense.

Comment: @MatthiasWendt You mean $V\times_XZ$?

Comment: At the level of rings, this is the map $K_n(R)\mapsto K_n(R/I)$ given by taking the class of a projective $R$-module $[P]$ to the class of the (finite projective dimension) $R/I$-module $P/IP$.  (Take the alternating sum of the classes of the projective modules occurring in a projective resolution of $P/IP$.)  The reason you need smoothness is to insure that $P/IP$ has finite projective dimension so that this class is well defined.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: yes, that was a typo.